# Field Not Writeable

Tags: apex, community, sharing, code

I have an `Apex Class` which updates the `User.IsPortalEnabled` field. But it throws the error:

> Field is Not writable.

How can I fix this error?

```
public without sharing class UserHandler
{
    public static void updateUser() { ... }
}
```

Comment: When do you actually update the User? Your code as shared does not commit anything to the database. Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

The user who is running this class/method must not have the permission to 'Edit' this field.
Make sure the running user has 'Manage Users' system permission. But this is a powerful permission. Check details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324398&type=1&mode=1)